# Capybara / Ruby - Trying to get a text from an invisible element and then convert it to string

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

I'm trying to get a specific text value from a CSS Selector that belongs an invisible element. After that I would like to convert the text (from the element) into a String to use the slice method later.

The invisible element I figured out how to find however I'm not finding a way to get the Text and then convert it to string.

The text that I want to get is in the p below (in the case, 3 cartões)

`<p class="list-header-num-cards hide js-num-cards">3 cartões</p>`

--

The CSS selector is
`<#board > div:nth-child(1) > div.list.js-list-content > div.list-header.js-list-header.u-clearfix.is-menu-shown > p`

**I've already tried commands like:**

`var = find('#board > div:nth-child(1) > div.list.js-list-content > div.list-header.js-list-header.u-clearfix.is-menu-shown > p', visible: false).value`

`var = find('#board > div:nth-child(1) > div.list.js-list-content > div.list-header.js-list-header.u-clearfix.is-menu-shown > p', visible: false).text`

However the var variable is not receiving the Text valeu and the test is passing.

Is I try to use 
`puts var`
the output is nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `text` method only returns visible text, since when testing an app/site you should really only worry about what the user can see. To get non-visible text you can pass `:all` to the text method

```
find('#board > div:nth-child(1) > div.list.js-list-content > div.list-header.js-list-header.u-clearfix.is-menu-shown > p', visible: false).text(:all)
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#text-instance_method

Also, note that using CSS selectors as specific as you are will lead to very brittle tests. Are all the classes and element type portions of the selector really necessary or would something a bit simpler like `#board > :nth-child(1) .list-header p` work too? Even that is probably more specific than you need but without seeing the actual HTML it's tough to say what would be better.